# Notepad++ all lines blue

Tags: notepad++

I am using notepad++ and I just started my first javascript project. When I loaded some javascript all the lines turned blue and it is really annoying to work with. Is there anybody that has experience with notepad++ and maybe knows how to resolve this.
Picture:

[image]

Thanks in advance
Remmert

Comment: Try *Language* -> *Normal Text*.

Comment: That's called *syntax highlighting*. Most developers like it, because it helps make it much easier to write code. Turn it off if you don't like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable any syntax highlighting, go to **Language** menu -> *Normal Text*.